# Do not keep lower-class badges that are implied by the attained higher-class ones

Tags: feature-request, badges

As an example, **Electorate** implies that **Civic Duty** has also been awarded, so there is no need to keep the latter. It is just visual noise (just look at the page of any very-active user).

Above example is a simple case of course, since other families have badges that are not exactly compatible, e.g.  Altruist and Benefactor, but you do get the point.

Comment: If badges are noise, so is reputation. Why not reset it when it reach 1000? Or 10000?

Comment: It is the implied ones that I consider noise.

Answer (score 8):

I love my badges and want to keep all of them, even if a bronze one has been topped by a silver or gold one.

That is not visual noise to me, that are awards I have got.

And in fact, all a user sees is a number next to a colored circle, in my opinion it does not matter if the number is **4028** ([John Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) bronze badges at the moment) or only **2976** (just an example, no idea what the real number would be).

Answer (score 1):

OK, I took your advice and looked in the [profile of a very active user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=badges&sort=name). That's what I see:

> [image]

True, there are badges that "repeat" themselves three times, even with same name, but each badge is on its own as well and marks some milestone that was reached, some achievement.

This reminds me of soldier medals:

[image]

I'm sure this person is proud in each and every medal, bronze, silver, and gold, and won't like to throw away or hide any of them.

So same with Stack Exchange badges: I don't want to delete or hide any badge just because there is a "better" badge.

Comment: Your grand-dad in the picture?

Comment: @rene almost! My grand-dad would have been 110 years old, if he would still be alive these days.... :D

Comment: Sorry to hear that but I'm sure he'll be proud on you for this answer ...

Answer (score 0):

I think this should at least be an option for this when viewing a user's badges (preferably they'd just always be hidden though), as well as (possibly) an option to show only non-tag badges/only tag badges

Comment: I don't think this should be an option (so -1 from me) but the tag/non-tag badges has merit (so +1 for me for that). Net gain: 0 votes.